# Traceback - Attribute Error: 'SpaceView3D' object has no attribute 'context'

Tags: modeling

I'm kind of new to blender, so I don't know all there is to know about this software. Anyway I have a issue, I've been watching the tutorials for Blender 2.8 and I'm following the guide. But for some reason an error occurs when I select the selection tool after editing in edit mode.
I've tried to uninstall and reinstall the software but the same problem occurs. 
Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it By doing following steps:

Just go to *Edit -> Prefrences*. In the bottom left corner click on *load factory  preferences*. It will solve your problem.